# What is wrong with my linear programming model?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, cplex

I tried solving this problem [image]

Here is my cplex code

[image]

I have mentioned stored[month] as float+ but in the final result I get negative values. What is wrong with my model? [image]

Comment: Why in objective function you have $\rm demand \times 0.3$? Shouldn't be $\rm stored \times 0.3$?

Comment: In the future, please use code blocks rather than screenshots. It makes it much easier for us to read, and also for us to copy and paste into our own systems to test and debug your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you get negative values because your model is relaxed by cplex since it is not feasible.
You should debug it.
Your

```
if (i==i)
```

looks very strange, I would change one i into 1

Plus to get help try to copy / paste code instead of screenshots

Comment: It was a mistake I changed it to if (i==1) , it worked , thanks